# finding domain names from ipV4 addresses

Tags: php, dns, ip

I am trying to get the domain names of certain ipV4 addresses using `gethostbyaddr()` function, but it does not return exactly what I'm looking for. For example this:

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr("173.252.110.27");
 echo $hostname;
```

will return: `edge-star-ecmp-13-frc1.facebook.com`

and google's ip address `73.252.110.27`

returns:`arn06s02-in-f5.1e100.net`

is there some way to get it to return just: facebook.com or google.com? Thanks

Comment: hah `.1e100.net` how clever of google :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook, Google, Yahoo etc. setup unique FQDNS for each of their servers on a secondary domain name (fbcdn.net, 1e100.net, yimg.com respectively). This lets them keep their primary domain name exclusively for their products. For your requirement, you'll have to manually map the secondary domain names returned by the `PTR` query to the company's primary domain name.

BTW, 1e100 stands for 1.0 * 10^100 which is a [Googol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol).

Comment: thanks for the info I have a better idea now of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) and requires a PTR record. Ask your host to set one up.

No, you're not going to be able to change the PTR records for Google/Facebook. What you see is what you get with those ones.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the info, that's good to know about the PTR records